# Initialize a variable to denote worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a snippet which throws an error, I assume because the variable s is not initialized.  How would I declare the variable s?

```
Dim X As Integer
Dim WS As Worksheet

'Look for existing sheets named "For Export
'If found, delete existing sheet
    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If s.Name = "For Export" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ' s.Delete


    End If
Next s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to search for `Option Explicit` in your code and to delete it. Then you would not be forced to declare every variable. However, if you are not fan of writing ugly & dirty code try with the following:

`Dim s as Sheet`

In general, it is better to use the `Worksheets` collection, instead of the `Sheets`. Thus:

```
Dim s as Worksheet
For each s in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

The `Sheets` collection contains both `Charts` and `Worksheets`, thus it is better to be more specific.